# MakeUppercase not working with KOMA-letter

Tags: koma-script, letters

I'm trying to use `MakeUppercase` to capitalize the subject of a KOMA-Letter:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{textcase}

\makeatletter%
\renewcommand{\subject@format}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\makeatother%

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{Recipient}

    \setkomavar{subject}{Foo Subject}

    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam}

    \blindtext

  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

However this doesn't work. The compilation fails with:

```
! Class scrlttr2 Error: KOMA-Script variable not defined.

See the scrlttr2 class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.16     \opening{Dear Sir or Madam}

? ^C! Interruption.
\GenericError  ...
```

If I'm using for example `\large` instead of `\MakeUppercase` everything works as expected. I also tried

```
`\addtokomafont{\MakeUppercase}
```

but this doesn't work either. What am I missing? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uppercase format is not supported. On the other hand, defining `\subject@format` as `\MakeUppercase` will most certainly fail, because the `\usekomavar` operation is not expandable.

Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass[
  subject=titled,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@subjfield}
  {\usekomavar{subject}}
  {\MakeUppercase{\usekomavarexp{subject}}}
  {}{}
\newcommand\usekomavarexp[1]{\@nameuse{scr@#1@var}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Recipient}

\setkomavar{subject}{Foo Subject}

\opening{Dear Sir or Madam}

\blindtext

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The easiest workaround is, of course, typing

```
\setkomavar{subject}{\MakeUppercase{Foo Subject}}
```